# Errors after changing compiler

Tags: compiler-construction

I am using Keil and I wanted to use DSP library.
I download GCC compiler, and change the compiler to GCC here: Project -> Manage -> Components, Environment -> Folder/Extensions Tab.
It ask me this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNBvB.png)

I agreed, after 1 minutes, I returned to my original compiler.
I needed to redefine all of my libraries paths.
And still, after building I have 13 errors:

```
Rebuild started: Project: FFT - Tutorial
*** Using Compiler 'V5.06 update 6 (build 750)', folder: 'C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCC\Bin'
Rebuild target 'FFT - Tutorial'
assembling startup_stm32l476xx.s...
compiling main.c...
../Src/main.c(98): error:  #254: type name is not allowed
    for (int32_t i= 0 ; i < SAMPLES ; i+=2)
../Src/main.c(98): error:  #65: expected a ";"
    for (int32_t i= 0 ; i < SAMPLES ; i+=2)
../Src/main.c(98): error:  #20: identifier "i" is undefined
    for (int32_t i= 0 ; i < SAMPLES ; i+=2)
../Src/main.c(145): error:  #254: type name is not allowed
        for(int16_t i=0; i<SAMPLES/2; i++)
../Src/main.c(145): error:  #65: expected a ";"
        for(int16_t i=0; i<SAMPLES/2; i++)
../Src/main.c: 0 warnings, 5 errors
compiling stm32l4xx_hal.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_i2c_ex.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_it.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_tim_ex.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_tim.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_msp.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_uart_ex.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_rcc.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_uart.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_flash.c...
../Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_flash.c(118): error:  #29: expected an expression
  FLASH_ProcessTypeDef pFlash = {.Lock = HAL_UNLOCKED, \
../Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_flash.c(119): error:  #29: expected an expression
                                 .ErrorCode = HAL_FLASH_ERROR_NONE, \
../Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_flash.c(120): error:  #29: expected an expression
                                 .ProcedureOnGoing = FLASH_PROC_NONE, \
../Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_flash.c(121): error:  #29: expected an expression
                                 .Address = 0U, \
../Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_flash.c(122): error:  #29: expected an expression
                                 .Bank = FLASH_BANK_1, \
../Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_flash.c(123): error:  #29: expected an expression
                                 .Page = 0U, \
../Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_flash.c(124): error:  #29: expected an expression
                                 .NbPagesToErase = 0U, \
../Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_flash.c(125): error:  #29: expected an expression
                                 .CacheToReactivate = FLASH_CACHE_DISABLED};
../Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_flash.c: 0 warnings, 8 errors
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_i2c.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_rcc_ex.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_flash_ex.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_gpio.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_pwr.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_dma_ex.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_dma.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_pwr_ex.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_cortex.c...
compiling stm32l4xx_hal_exti.c...
compiling system_stm32l4xx.c...
".\FFT - Tutorial.axf" - 13 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).
Target not created.
Build Time Elapsed:  00:00:02
```

What I forgot to config?
(I didnt add my code, because it not matter to my problem, it worked perfect before I changed my compiler)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that when you reverted to default settings, the compiler reverted to using the ISO C90 standard. According to the [on-line manual](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124192674.htm), the option `--c90`, which enables only C90 and some ARM extensions, is the default setting.

You're trying to compile code which uses features which have been part of C for more than two decades, but are not part of C90. The errors you quote refer to a couple of these features: [declaring local variables in a `for` statement](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124240335.htm), and out-of-order initialisation using ["designated initialisers"](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124238260.htm) for aggregate datatypes.

Apparently, the Keil compiler is perfectly capable of compiling the C language. You merely need to specify the `--c99` option. (I don't know where you need to put that configuration, but I'm sure you'll be able to find it.)

Comment: Thank you!
I saw this option in Target's option -> c/c++